# What do we call English with dots and dashes?

Tags: word-request

In our native languages, pronunciations of the words are different if we write it in normal English. For that reason, we have a different set of alphabet. Such writing helps us speak *correct pronunciation.* This specially happens in writing language like *Sanskrit* in English.

What do we call that English? Here is the example:

[image: Sanskrit written in special English]

Comment: From the title, I came here expecting a Morse code question... but this is much more interesting, in my opinion.

Comment: It's important to understand the difference between a language and a script. You're transcribing from Devanagari script to Latin script, but the language is still Sanskrit, not English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while this is a good linguistics question, it is not about learning English.

Comment: [Transliteration#Difference_from_transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration#Difference_from_transcription)

Comment: @user3169 it actually *is* on topic: OP is searching for an expression to describe the concept of „dots and dashes around letters“ in English (tag: word-request), not about linguistics. The rest is simply explaining the context of the question. That I (and others) have chosen to add some linguistic remarks is like some„extra background information“ I gave to round off my answer. The core question asks for the term *diacritics*, which I answer in the last sentence of my answer below.

Comment: In addition to the answer (*diacricic marks*), you might have a specific name for the transliteration rules and letter/mark meanings. For example, I'm familiar with Chinese being written in “pinyin”, which is what I would ask for if I wanted a Latin character representation.  Wade is a *different* one.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Technically, you are not writing “in English”, you are using a [Latin script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script)<sup>1</sup> with [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)<sup>2</sup> to [transcribe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcribe)<sup>3</sup> Sanskrit.

If you want a writer to use the “dots and dashes”, ask them to “use diacritic marks”.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> the letters of the English and many other western languages

<sup>2</sup> the dots and dashes

<sup>3</sup> to write in another script</sub>

Comment: Ad 1. Technically it's not "letters of English (...) language" but letters of Latin language reused later by English and many other languages;)

Comment: @el.pescado that's what I said? I was referring to everyday use, not historic roots.

Comment: @el.pescado It is the letters that are in use in the English written language, so even though it was appropriated for that use rather than originated there, in my opinion it's correct to say that the Latin script is "the letters of the English (...) language". The letters aren't _owned_ by the English language, but they are used by it.

Comment: Sometimes diacritics are (less accurately) referred to as "accents". I feel your average speaker would be more likely to understand that term than "diacritics" but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Muzer: I'd only expect accents to cover á, à and â. This already doesn't include German umlauts like ä and other rather common diacritics like ñ or ç. That said, I'm from Germany and influenced by local customs, so YMMV (though I guess the situation would be similar in the UK/Ireland).

Comment: Of course the average (native) English speaker wouldn't understand what pronounciation was intended to be indicated by the diacritic marks.  Speakers of other languages that are written in the Latin alphabet might, but the meanings could well be different for different languages.

Comment: @jamesqf The pronunciation indicated by letters even without any diacritics varies between languages (examples from Hungarian: Hungarian c is like English ts, s is like sh, j is like y as a consonant; and then there's the digraphs like sz, gy, cs). So no, speakers of any random non-Sanskrit language that uses the latin script with those diacritics probably can't pronounce Sanskrit much more reliably than an English speaker.

Comment: @hoffmale All the diacritics (including accents, umlaut, vergulilla, cedilla) change the sound and are thus generally covered by being called "accents" or "accent marks" in English.

Comment: @Arthur "English letters" or "the English alphabet" is used to refer to the particular use of Latin script (with such evolutions as the invention of W, the import and then dropping from use of Þ and so on) in English. That is not how Latin script is used with Sanskrit, so it would be the wrong term.

Comment: Why did you edit the answer to use "transcribe" rather than "transliterate"? "Transcribe" does not mean "to write in another script".

Comment: Yes, should be "transliterate" rather than "transcribe".

Answer (score 31):

The process of converting the letters of one script into the letters of another is called "transliteration"

> Definition of TRANSLITERATE
>
> transliterated; transliterating
>
> transitive verb
>
> :to represent or spell in the characters of another alphabet
>
> — transliteration [...] noun
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transliterate

Indeed the scheme used in your OP is called [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration) (International Alphabet for Sanskrit Transliteration).

You should ask for a "transliteration" or a transliterated version.

Now, for sure, sarvasya chaahaN hridi ... is also a transliteration, but it's not an academic/scientific transliteration. Both of these words ('academic' and 'scientific') are used for [precise, scholarly transliterations of Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_transliteration_of_Cyrillic) and I see no reason why they cannot be used more generally. If you want a precise, scholarly transliteration, what you must really do is specify the scheme, which is more important. There is nothing inherently wrong with the Indian government-approved [Hunterian transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunterian_transliteration)  which uses few diacritics, or Harvard-Kyoto which uses its own schemes with no diacritics at all, but also doesn't strive to reflect pronunciation closely. So what you must do is specify the transliteration scheme which you are using. For example, IAST will transliterate ए as e whereas ISO15919 will use ē. Both, however, will transliterate आ as ā. Many transliteration schemes use diacritics. You can ask for a transliteration with diacritics, but you must specify the scheme, because different schemes may use different diacritics or use diacritics for different purposes.

Answer (score 3):

These are called diacritical marks.

Comment: So, what should I ask? Use 'diacritical English' for the quotes?

Comment: No, ask them to "transliterate the text into Roman letters with diacritics" or "transliterate using IAST" if they know what IAST is.

Answer (score -1):

Writing foreign language in English alphabet is called Romanization because the letters we use are actually Latin.

Comment: That doesn’t address the “dots and dashes” part which was the main part of the question.